# Aerolinia con descuentos de edades python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quisiera que el codigo haga el descuento dependiendo la edad si tiene 4 no paga ticket si
tiene entre 5 a 10 paga la mitad, si tien de 11 a 17 pagara un 75% del ticket si tiene de 18 a
50 es completo pero si pasa los 60 paga un 80% del ticket pero no me sale los descuentos me
podrian ayudar.
Ya solo seri eso lo que me faltaria por hacer para que el programa corra sin inconveniente
alguno

```
nombre=input("Ingrese Nombre Completo: ")
def main():
    print("""      
                     ****AEROLINEA ABC****""")
    print("""
               ---SISTEMA DE VENTAS DE TICKETS--- """)
    print("""  
     _________________________________________________ 
    |                       |                         |
    |         DESTINO       |   VALOR DEL TIQUETE     |
    |_______________________|_________________________|
    |         GUAYAQUIL     |     $100                |
    |         QUITO         |     $150                |
    |         CUENCA        |     $120                |
    |         AMBATO        |     $130                |
    |         OTROS         |     $200                |
    |_________________________________________________|
    """)
    tasa=45
    seguro = 25

    destino = input("Digite su destino: ")
    edadPasajero = eval(input("Digite edad del pasajero: "))

    
#En esta parte quisiera que valide los que es la ciudad y dependiendo la edad haga el 
#descuento respectivo a los if pero me arroja simplemente el valor neto  
    

    if (destino.lower() == "Guayaquil") or (destino.lower() == "guayaquil"):
        valorBaseViaje = 100
    elif (destino.lower() == "Quito") or (destino.lower() == "quito"):
        valorBaseViaje = 150
    elif (destino.lower() == "Cuenca") or (destino.lower() == "cuenca"):
        valorBaseViaje = 120
    elif (destino.lower() == "Ambato") or (destino.lower() == "ambato"):
        valorBaseViaje = 130
    else:
        valorBaseViaje = 200
        
    if edadPasajero >=0 and edadPasajero<=4:
        edadPasajero=valorBaseViaje-valorBaseViaje
        print("Ticket sin costo")
    elif edadPasajero >4 and edadPasajero<=10:
        valorEdad = valorBaseViaje-valorBaseViaje/2
    elif edadPasajero >=11 and edadPasajero<=17:
        valorEdad = valorBaseViaje*0.75
    elif edadPasajero >=18 and edadPasajero<=50:
        valorEdad = valorBaseViaje
    elif edadPasajero >60:
        valorEdad = valorBaseViaje*0.80

    precioTotal = valorBaseViaje +(tasa + seguro)
    precioTotal = valorBaseViaje
    print(f"El valor del viaje es: {precioTotal}")  

main()
```

Comment: El problema es que estas escribiendo el valor en `valorEdad` en lugar de `valorBaseViaje` y te hace falta evaluar si la edad es entre 50 y 60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Hay varios errores de concepto en tu código

El problema principal de tu pregunta es que te devuelve el valor neto, esto es porque en tus `if` donde evaluas la edad del pasajero creas una variable `valorEdad` pero al calcular el `precioTotal` estas utilizando nuevamente el `valorBaseViaje` es decir, nunca utilizas el `valorEdad` que calculaste en los `if`

En realidad podrías utilizar la misma variable `valorBaseViaje` ya que solo procesas un pasajero a la vez y no hace falta conservar el valor original del viaje

Otras cosas que podrías mejorar son:

Cuando evaluas el destino no hace falta que hagas

```
(destino.lower() == "Guayaquil") or (destino.lower() == "guayaquil")
```

Ya que cuando haces `destino.lower()` esto convierte **todas** las letras de `destino` a minúsculas, por lo que el resultado nunca sería "Guayaquil", esa parte la puedes eliminar

Otra cosa que podrías optimizar es la evaluación de edades

Cuando comparas un rango de edades puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
if limiteInferior <= valorAEvaluar <= limiteSuperior:
```

Esto hace el código más legible y evita el uso de `and`

También podrías utilizar operadores de asignación, cuando tienes que calcular un número donde el resultado depende del valor actual del número, por ejemplo

```
valorBaseViaje = valorBaseViaje * 0.80
```

Puedes obtener el mismo resultado utilizando el operador de asignación `*=` de esta forma

```
valorBaseViaje *= 0.80
```

Por último, en la parte donde calculas el `precioTotal` tienes dos lineas, una donde incluyes la `tasa` y el `seguro` pero luego sobreescribes el valor de `precioTotal` por el valor neto del viaje `valorBaseViaje` por lo que siempre te devuelve ese valor.

**Nota:** En tu pregunta no mencionas que precio se debe utilizar para el rango de 50-60, en este caso lo incluí en el mismo rango de 18-50, que por cierto, al ser el único escenario donde no hay ningún precio especial se puede eliminar del if, de esa forma `valorBaseViaje` no se modifica, es decir, no tiene ningún descuento

Ejemplo completo aplicando los consejos antes mencionados:

```
nombre=input("Ingrese Nombre Completo: ")
def main():
    print("""      
                     ****AEROLINEA ABC****""")
    print("""
               ---SISTEMA DE VENTAS DE TICKETS--- """)
    print("""  
     _________________________________________________ 
    |                       |                         |
    |         DESTINO       |   VALOR DEL TIQUETE     |
    |_______________________|_________________________|
    |         GUAYAQUIL     |     $100                |
    |         QUITO         |     $150                |
    |         CUENCA        |     $120                |
    |         AMBATO        |     $130                |
    |         OTROS         |     $200                |
    |_________________________________________________|
    """)
    tasa = 45
    seguro = 25

    destino = input("Digite su destino: ")
    edadPasajero = eval(input("Digite edad del pasajero: "))
    
    if destino.lower() == "guayaquil":
        valorBaseViaje = 100
    elif destino.lower() == "quito":
        valorBaseViaje = 150
    elif destino.lower() == "cuenca":
        valorBaseViaje = 120
    elif destino.lower() == "ambato":
        valorBaseViaje = 130
    else:
        valorBaseViaje = 200

    if 0 <= edadPasajero <= 4:
        valorBaseViaje = 0
        print("Ticket sin costo")
    elif 4 < edadPasajero <= 10:
        valorBaseViaje /= 2
    elif 10 < edadPasajero <= 17:
        valorBaseViaje *= 0.75
    elif edadPasajero > 60:
        valorBaseViaje *= 0.80

    precioTotal = valorBaseViaje + tasa + seguro
    print(f"El valor del viaje es: {precioTotal}")  

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Este código sería mucho más legible y [escalable](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalabilidad) si trabajas con una estructura que puedes usar como base de datos, como un diccionario o un JSON.

Supongamos un diccionario de esta forma:

```py
db = {
    'tasa' : 45,
    'seguro' : 25,
    'tarifa' : {
        'guayaquil':100, 'quito':150, 'cuenca':120, 'ambato':130, 'otros':200
    },
    'desc' : {0:100, 5:50, 11:25, 18:0, 61:20}
}
```

De esta forma sería sencillo agregar/quitar/modificar tarifas, rutas y descuentos; además de que el programa se reduciría en complejidad a algo tan simple como:

```py
destino = input("Digite su destino: ").lower()
edadPasajero = int(input("Digite edad del pasajero: "))

precio = db['tarifa'][destino]
descuento = 0.0
for edad_tarifa, desc_porc in db['desc'].items():
    if edad_tarifa <= edadPasajero:
        descuento = precio * (desc_porc/100)

costo_total = precio - descuento + db['tasa'] + db['seguro']
```

Ahora puedes hacer una salida formateada con los datos, como una factura:

```py
print()
print(f"Destino:  {destino.upper()}")
print(f"Precio:   ${precio:.2f}")
print(f"Desc:    -${descuento:.2f}")
print(f"Tasa:     ${db['tasa']:.2f}")
print(f"Seguro:   ${db['seguro']:.2f}")
print("-----------------")
print(f"Total:    ${costo_total:.2f}")
```

Esto produce una salida como esta:

```
Digite su destino: Quito
Digite edad del pasajero: 16

Destino:  QUITO
Precio:   $150.00
Desc:    -$37.50
Tasa:     $45.00
Seguro:   $25.00
-----------------
Total:    $182.50
```

Obviamente al programa le falta las capturas de errores de las entradas, también verificar si el destino introducido existe. También puedes (y debes) imprimir el menú y tarifas usando el mismo arreglo `db`.